# Reference Request - Typed First-Order-Logic Book

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic

There are many great references for computer scientists interested in untyped first order logic, such as Melvin Fitting's "First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving" or John Harrison's "Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning".

However, I have been having difficulty finding a solid reference that specifically deals with typed (or "many-sorted") first-order logic.

While much knowledge of untyped first-order logic transfers well to a typed setting,  there are some interesting questions specific to typed first-order logic that I am interested in seeing a rigorous treatment of, possibly with sample implementations. An obvious example is type-checking, but another is whether it is useful in a typed setting to syntactically distinguish between formulas and terms, or if formulas should just be treated as terms of type `Bool`, and the consequences such decisions have on computing normal forms. I'm sure there are other interesting questions as well.

Are there any books you can recommend that have a focus, or even just a lengthy enough chapter, specifically dealing with typed first-order logic?

EDIT: There are some resources listed on Wikipedia for Many-Sorted Logic, however many have to do with Order-Sorted Logic (which is a more sophisticated kind of typed logic than I am looking for, I am only looking for a basic many-sorted logic with disjoint types), or are about one specific kind of algorithm (e.g. Resolution).

One suggestion on there that I like is the first chapter of Calogero G. Zarba's  [decision theory lecture notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20070608182648/http://react.cs.uni-sb.de/~zarba/notes.html), though it does not really go into the depth I was hoping for and is written more as a summary of definitions, whereas I was hoping more for a thorough book along the lines of Fitting or Harrison.

Perhaps this is too much to hope for as simple many-sorted first-order logic is very similar to untyped first-order logic.

Comment: Nice question. Among [the references given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic#References), can you edit the question to show how the one that is closest to your goal falls short still?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the feedback!